# Returning most recent record with an outer join

Tags: t-sql

I have a query that returns the following data:

```
F_id - P_id - Date
----------------------
1001 - 0121 - 01/01/14
NULL - 0122 - NULL
1002 - 0123 - 01/06/14
1003 - 0123 - 01/04/14
NULL - 0124 - NULL
1004 - 0125 - 01/04/14
1005 - 0125 - 02/04/14
1006 - 0125 - 07/07/14
```

F_id is a form Id,  P_id is a person identifier which is outer joined from another table and Date is the date the form was entered.
Not all persons have had a form entered, some have one, and some have several.
What I am trying to do is bring back the most recent F_id and Date for each person in the list, but leave it as NULL if they have not had a form entered.
Like So:

```
F_id - P_id - Date
--------------------------
1001 - 0121 - 01/01/14
NULL - 0122 - NULL
1003 - 0123 - 01/04/14
NULL - 0124 - NULL
1006 - 0125 - 07/07/14
```

I have tried using MAX(F_id) in a variety of ways, but with no luck.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to tell us the platform you are using -- oracle or ms server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work, if you current sql is

```
 select blah from blah
```

change it to

```
select * from
(
  select blah,
      row_number() over (partition by p_id order by F_id desc) as rn
  from blah
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

you may need

```
     row_number() over (partition by p_id order by coalesce(F_id,0) desc) as rn
```

not sure off the top of my head -- see if the results are different.